# Linking CSS to HTML

Tags: html, css, file, directory

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WhVf.png)first time posting here. I restructured all the files on my website since I wanted to experiment with how to organize files, and I ran into a few issues. When I launch the site HTML appears but the CSS stylesheet doesn't seem to want to attach. I also think the js sheet is also not attaching properly but can't test it till css shows up. I double-checked spelling as well as placed the index.html on the root folder but still nothing I'll post the code below and hopefully someone can help me out. I appreciate you guys.

[image]

[image: This is the updated code with relative path]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you link a CSS or JS file to an HTML file, you need to provide a *relative* path from the HTML file to the CSS or JS file. In this case, it looks like `index.html` is already in the `Root` directory, so you shouldn't include that in the CSS file paths. The relative path to the css files (the path from the directory where index.html is to where the css file is) would be `/Css/index.css`, and the same for your javascript files (`/Scripts/index.js`).

Comment: This fixed the issue, thank you so much for saving me so much time!